# Calculating cubic root for negative number

Tags: javascript, math

So, to be short,

> <sup>3</sup>√(-8) = (-8)<sup>1/3</sup>

```
console.log(Math.pow(-8,1/3));
//Should be -2
```

But when I test it out, it outputs

```
NaN
```

Why? Is it a bug or it is expected to be like this in the first place? I am using JavaScript to draw graphs, but this messes up the graph.

Comment: multiply 8^1/3 by -1 :-)

Comment: There is a native [cubic root in ES6](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29740048/1090562)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use this snippet to calculate it. It also works for other powers, e.g. `1/4`, `1/5`, etc.

```
function nthroot(x, n) {
  try {
    var negate = n % 2 == 1 && x < 0;
    if(negate)
      x = -x;
    var possible = Math.pow(x, 1 / n);
    n = Math.pow(possible, n);
    if(Math.abs(x - n) < 1 && (x > 0 == n > 0))
      return negate ? -possible : possible;
  } catch(e){}
}

nthroot(-8, 3);
```

Source: http://gotochriswest.com/blog/2011/05/06/cube-root-an-beyond/

A faster approach for just calculating the cubic root:

```
Math.cbrt = function(x) {
    var sign = x === 0 ? 0 : x > 0 ? 1 : -1;

    return sign * Math.pow(Math.abs(x), 1 / 3);
}

Math.cbrt(-8);
```

**Update**

To find an integer based cubic root, you can use the following function, inspired by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/263113):

```
// positive-only cubic root approximation
function cbrt(n)
{
    var a = n; // note: this is a non optimized assumption

    while (a * a * a > n) {
        a = Math.floor((2 * a + (n / (a * a))) / 3);
    }

    return a;
}
```

It starts with an assumption that converges to the closest integer `a` for which `a^3 <= n`. This function can be adjusted in the same way to support a negative base.

Comment: @Derek Great, I've added a smaller function for just the cubic root.

Comment: Surely for consistency you should return 'NaN' rather than throwing. Incidentally, when would that code ever throw?

Answer (score 10):

There's no bug; you are raising a negative number to a fractional power; hence, the NaN.

The top hit on google for this is from [Dr Math](https://web.archive.org/web/20180114135902/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/62979.html) the explanation is pretty good.  It says for for real numbers (not complex numbers anyway), a negative number raised to a fractional power may not be a real number.  The simplest example is probably

-4 ^ (1/2)

which is essentially computing the square root of -4.  Even though the cubic root of -8 does have real solutions, I think that most software libraries find it more efficient not to do all the complex arithmetic and return NaN only when the imaginary part is nonzero and give you the nice real answer otherwise.

**EDIT**

Just to make absolutely clear that `NaN` is the intended result, [see the official ECMAScript 5.1 Specification, Section 15.8.2.13](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.13).  It says:

> If x<0 and x is finite and y is finite and y is not an integer, the result is NaN.

Again, even though SOME instances of raising negative numbers to fractional powers have exactly one real root, many languages just do the NaN thing for all cases of negative numbers to fractional roots.

Please do not think JavaScript is the only such language.  [C++ does the same thing](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/):

> If x is finite negative and y is finite but not an integer value, it causes a domain error.

Comment: So how do I do `3√(-8)` without doing `8^(1/3)`?

Comment: You can switch to Wolfram Alpha, which is better at handling these things than JavaScript: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-8+%5E+%281%2F3%29 :)  Seriously JavaScript just takes the easy way out and says NaN for these, because they are often complex numbers, which JavaScript does not natively support.

Comment: +1, some of the *math forum* answer should probably be replicated as part of *your*

Comment: @RayToal: actually hold on, shouldn't the correct WA link be [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-8%29+%5E+%281%2F3%29)?

Comment: He is raising a negative number to a rational power with odd denominator, which is perfectly possible, and has exactly one real root. It's crappy approximations by JavaScript that is acting up here.

Comment: It's not just JavaScript that does this.  C++ gives an error there too.  And it is not really a "crappy approximation." I bet the decision to just not do ANY negative numbers to fractional exponents is very common for a language's standard pow implementation on reals.

Answer (score 7):

Two key problems:

1. Mathematically, there are multiple cubic roots of a negative number: -2, but also 2 complex roots (see [cube roots of unity](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cube+roots+of+unity)).
2. Javascript's `Math` object (and most other standard math libraries) will not do fractional powers of negative numbers. It converts the fractional power to a float before the function receives it, so you are asking the function to compute a floating point power of a negative number, which may or may not have a real solution. So it does the pragmatic thing and refuses to attempt to calculate such a value.

If you want to get the correct answer, you'll need to decide how mathematically correct you want to be, and write those rules into a non-standard implementation of `pow`.

All library functions are limited to avoid excessive calculation times and unnecessary complexity.

Comment: There are multiple cube roots of any positive number too. To be precise, for any real number `x` and positive integer `n` there are exactly `n` unique values for `y` over the complex plane satisfying `x=y^n`. This stems directly from the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Answer (score 6):

I like the other answers, but how about overriding `Math.pow` so it would be able to work with *all* nth roots of negative numbers:

```
//keep the original method for proxying
Math.pow_ = Math.pow;

//redefine the method
Math.pow = function(_base, _exponent) {
  if (_base < 0) {
    if (Math.abs(_exponent) < 1) {
      //we're calculating nth root of _base, where n === 1/_exponent
      if (1 / _exponent % 2 === 0) {
        //nth root of a negative number is imaginary when n is even, we could return
        //a string like "123i" but this would completely mess up further computation
        return NaN;
      }/*else if (1 / _exponent % 2 !== 0)*/
      //nth root of a negative number when n is odd
      return -Math.pow_(Math.abs(_base), _exponent);
    }
  }/*else if (_base >=0)*/
  //run the original method, nothing will go wrong
  return Math.pow_(_base, _exponent);
};
```

[Fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/J5zVt/1/) with some test cases, give me a shout if you spot a bug!

Comment: I don't really like `pow_` floating around... Is it possible to put the original `pow` inside the new `pow`?

Comment: @Derek: yeah, that's what I'm doing. `pow` becomes `pow_`, or could be `pow_legacy` or whatever you need

Comment: No, I mean I don't want an extra variable `Math.pow_`. I am thinking something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/D32Td/

Comment: @Derek: I see; my preference would be to avoid it, don't let that influence you :) At this stage I'm more concerned about possibly producing erroneous results than code semantics

Comment: +1 for explaining the steps and also returning NaN instead of throwing.

Answer (score 4):

So I see a bunch of methods that revolve around `Math.pow(...)` which is cool, but based on the wording of the bounty I'm proposing a slightly different approach.

There are several computational approximations for solving roots, some taking quicker steps than others. Ultimately the stopping point comes down to the degree of precision desired(it's really up to you/the problem being solved).

I'm not going to explain the math in fine detail, but **the following are implementations of cubed root approximations** that passed the target test(bounty test - also added negative range, because of the question title). Each iteration in the loop (see the `while(Math.abs(xi-xi0)>precision)` loops in each method) gets a step closer to the desired precision. Once precision is achieved a format is applied to the number so it's as precise as the calculation derived from the iteration.

```
var precision = 0.0000000000001;
function test_cuberoot_fn(fn) { 
    var tested = 0, 
    failed = 0; 
    for (var i = -100; i < 100; i++) { 
        var root = fn(i*i*i); 
        if (i !== root) { 
            console.log(i, root); 
            failed++; 
        } 
        tested++; 
    } 
    if (failed) { 
        console.log("failed %d / %d", failed, tested); 
    }else{
        console.log("Passed test");
    }
}
test_cuberoot_fn(newtonMethod);
test_cuberoot_fn(halleysMethod);
```

**Newton's approximation Implementation**

```
function newtonMethod(cube){
    if(cube == 0){//only John Skeet and Chuck Norris
        return 0; //can divide by zero, we'll have
    }             //to settle for check and return
    var xi = 1;
    var xi0 = -1;
    while(Math.abs(xi-xi0)>precision){//precision = 0.0000000000001
        xi0=xi;
        xi = (1/3)*((cube/(xi*xi))+2*xi);
    }
    return Number(xi.toPrecision(12));
}
```

**Halley's approximation Implementation**
*note* Halley's approximation takes quicker steps to solving the cube, so it's computationally faster than newton's approximation.

```
function halleysMethod(cube){
    if(cube == 0){//only John Skeet and Chuck Norris
        return 0; //can divide by zero, we'll have
    }             //to settle for check and return
    var xi = 1;
    var xi0 = -1;
    while(Math.abs(xi-xi0)>precision){//precision = 0.0000000000001
        xi0=xi;
        xi = xi*((xi*xi*xi + 2*cube)/(2*xi*xi*xi+cube));
    }
    return Number(xi.toPrecision(12));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's Working in Chrome Console

```
function cubeRoot(number) {
    var num = number;
    var temp = 1;
    var inverse = 1 / 3;
    if (num < 0) {
        num = -num;
        temp = -1;
    }
    var res = Math.pow(num, inverse);
    var acc = res - Math.floor(res);
    if (acc <= 0.00001)
        res = Math.floor(res);
    else if (acc >= 0.99999)
        res = Math.ceil(res);
    return (temp * res);
}

cubeRoot(-64) // -4
cubeRoot(64)  //  4
```

Answer (score 2):

As a heads up, in ES6 there is now a Math.cbrt function.

In my testing in Google chrome it appears to work almost twice as fast as Math.pow. Interestingly I had to add up the results otherwise chrome did a better job of optimizing away the pow function.

```
//do a performance test on the cube root function from es6
var start=0, end=0, k=0;
start = performance.now();
k=0;
for (var i=0.0; i<10000000.0; i+=1.0)
{
    var j = Math.cbrt(i);
    //k+=j;
}
end = performance.now();
console.log("cbrt took:" + (end-start),k);
k=0;
start = performance.now();
for (var i=0.0; i<10000000.0; i+=1.0)
{
    var j = Math.pow(i,0.33333333);
    //k+=j;
}
end = performance.now();
console.log("pow took:" + (end-start),k);
k=0;
start = performance.now();
for (var i=0.0; i<10000000.0; i+=1.0)
{
    var j = Math.cbrt(i);
    k+=j;
}
end = performance.now();
console.log("cbrt took:" + (end-start),k);
k=0;
start = performance.now();
for (var i=0.0; i<10000000.0; i+=1.0)
{
    var j = Math.pow(i,0.33333333);
    k+=j;
}
end = performance.now();
console.log("pow took:" + (end-start),k);
```

Result:

```
cbrt took:468.28200000163633 0
pow took:77.21999999921536 0
cbrt took:546.8039999977918 1615825909.5248165
pow took:869.1149999940535 1615825826.7510242
```

Answer (score 1):

//aren't cube roots of negative numbers the same as positive, except for the sign?

```
Math.cubeRoot= function(n, r){
    var sign= (n<0)? -1: 1;
    return sign*Math.pow(Math.abs(n), 1/3);
}
Math.cubeRoot(-8)

/*  returned value: (Number)
-2
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Just want to highlight that in ES6 there is a [native cubic root](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cbrt) function. So you can just do this (check the support [here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#Math_methods_Math.cbrt))

`Math.cbrt(-8)` will return you `-2`

Answer (score 0):

this works with negative number and negative exponent:

```js
function nthRoot(x = 0, r = 1) {
  if (x < 0) {
    if (r % 2 === 1) return -nthRoot(-x, r)
    if (r % 2 === -1) return -1 / nthRoot(-x, -r)
  }
  return x ** (1 / r)
}
```

examples:

```
nthRoot( 16,  2)   4
nthRoot( 16, -2)   0.25
nthRoot(-16,  2)   NaN
nthRoot(-16, -2)   NaN
nthRoot( 27,  3)   3
nthRoot( 27, -3)   0.3333333333333333
nthRoot(-27,  3)   -3
nthRoot(-27, -3)   -0.3333333333333333
```